# Queen of Mars is in love with Duck Dodgers

Tags: cartoon

In the [new version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_%28TV_series%29) of [*Duck Dodgers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers), the queen of Mars seems to be in love with Duck Dodgers. However, in one episode, Dodgers seems to run away from his engagement/wedding with the queen. Why does Dodgers not sacrifice himself to end the enemity between the Planet Earth and the Planet Mars?

Comment: This question is being discussed in [this Meta thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/467/where-should-we-stand-on-why-didnt-so-in-so-do-x-y-z-type-questions).

Comment: Because it's funnier that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Duck Dodgers is of a VERY limited intelligence and totally, completely, 100% selfish.  He's unable to think beyond his immediate wants and needs and doesn't care what anyone around him says.

It's completely in character for him to plan something and change his mind at the last minute because something else grabs his attention.

Think of him as having a severe case of narcissism coupled with extreme ADD.